# String tokenizer in c

Tags: c, string, replace, character, tokenize

the following code will break down the string command using space i.e " " and a full stop i.e.  "."     What if i want to break down command using the occurrence of both the space and full stop (at the same time) and not each by themselves e.g. a command like: 'hello .how are you' will be broken into the pieces (ignoring the quotes) 
[hello]
[how are you today]

```
char *token2 = strtok(command, " .");
```

Comment: You need to either write your own tokenizer, or use a third party parser/lexer generator (like `lex`) or library (I only know a C++ parser library `boost::spirit`, not any C library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it pretty easily with `strstr`:

```
char *strstrtok(char *str, char *delim)
{
    static char *prev;
    if (!str) str = prev;
    if (str) {
        char *end = strstr(str, delim);
        if (end) {
            prev = end + strlen(delim);
            *end = 0;
        } else {
            prev = 0;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

This is pretty much exactly the same as the implementation of `strtok`, just calling `strstr` and `strlen` instead of `strcspn` and `strspn`.  It also might return empty tokens (if there are two consecutive delimiters or a delimiter at either end); you can arrange to ignore those if you would prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet might just be to crawl your input with `strstr`, which finds occurrences of a substring, and manually tokenize on those.

It's a common question you ask, but I've yet to see a particularly elegant solution. The above is straightforward and workable, however.